# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject: You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0

Tags: c#, json.net, json-deserialization, .net-framework-version

I want to use the following in my Universal Windows app

`Status_String status_deser = JsonNet.Deserialize<Status_String>(str_extracted_json);`

or

`Status_String status_deser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Status_String>(str_extracted_json);`

When I put either of these in, I get the response

> The type 'Stream' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'

As suggested elsewhere, I add a reference to

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.0\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\netstandard.dll

But then I get the message

> Cannot find type System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationBinder in module netstandard.dll

I've also installed 'NETStandard.Library' via Nuget, no change. I've also tried adding the following to my .csproj file

`<ItemGroup> <Reference Include="netstandard" /> </ItemGroup>`

How do I make this work?

Comment: What framework version is your project targeting?

Comment: Well, it isn't listed under Application properties, I guess it's because it's a Universal Windows app?

Comment: I found a workaround for now, Newtonsoft.Json version 6.0.8 builds and runs fine